# How to extract a folder path in WIX?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I want to extract a folder path other than an installation directory using a second folder browser dialog.

```
 <Control Id="edtDataStoreLocation" Type="PathEdit" X="45" Y="174" Height="18" Width="220"Property="MyProperty"/>

  <Control Id="btnStoreLocation" Type="PushButton" X="270" Y="175" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Browse" >
     <Publish Property="SelectFolderDialog_Property" Value="MyProperty" Order="1">1</Publish>
     <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="SelectFolderDialog" Order="2">1</Publish>
  </Control>
```

This throws up an error when I click **OK** in the browser dialog. Following is the error.

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2727.

How can i select a folder and extract this path to **MyProperty** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with custom action if you want :

```
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = @"PFX Files|*.ipa",
            Title = @"Add IPA file"
        };
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doSometh with the result;

        }
```

Comment: So this means we cannot use existing properties to do this task ?

Comment: One other question. This  folder browser dialog box does not have the actual behavior of an actual folder browser dialog. The dialog box is not always on top of the installer. How to overcome this problem ?

Comment: You probably  use wix UI  , there must  be some option to hide the current dialog window, but im not sure. I  am using custom wpf UI as bootstrapper and this browse dialog is always on top(although its really easy to hide window in wpf).